# Mysql counting row with specific attributes

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

So, here is my table:

```
Id  | name | Store   
001 | John | A   
001 | John | A     
001 | John | A       
001 | John | B
001 | John | B 
001 | John | D
002 | Bob  | B 
002 | Bob  | C 
003 | Dave | C 
004 | Pamela | A
004 | Pamela | B
004 | Pamela | C 
005 | Nick   | D
005 | Nick   | D
005 | Nick   | D
```

1. How can I select then count all people having shopped at A AND B, then
2. A AND B ONLY?
3. A OR B BUT NO OTHER?
4. D ONLY ?

In my example the expected result is: (1) John + Pamela, (2) John, (3) John (4) Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names of people shopping at A *and* B (and possibly elsewhere):

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Store = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND   -- A is present
       SUM(CASE WHEN Store = 'B' THEN 1 END) > 0       -- B is present
```

Names of people having at A *or* B (but no other):

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN Store = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0 OR           -- A is present
        SUM(CASE WHEN Store = 'B' THEN 1 END) > 0) AND         -- B is present
       SUM(CASE WHEN Store NOT IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 END) = 0   -- only A or B
```

Names of people who shopped *only* at A and B:

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Store = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND   -- A is present
       SUM(CASE WHEN Store = 'B' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND   -- B is present
       COUNT(DISTINCT Store) = 2                       -- only A and B are present
```

Names of people who shopped only at store D:

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Store <> 'D' THEN 1 END) = 0      -- only store D
```

**Demo for second query here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Great answers Tim and Gordon. How about for a new case (3) A OR B but no other?

Comment: I have updated my question to cover more cases. How about only at D?

Answer (score 2):

I like to approach these queries using `group by` and `having`:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(store = 'A') > 0 and
       sum(store = 'B') > 0;
```

This gets people who have shopped at both stores.  If you only want only those two stores and no other ones:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(store = 'A') > 0 and
       sum(store = 'B') > 0 and
       sum(store not in ('A', 'B')) = 0;
```